# Computation time of Smith normal form in Maple

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra, smith-normal-form

I am using Maple to compute the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) (SNF) of a $120 \times 120$ matrix and it seems that I will never get an answer back. I have checked my code for small cases and I believe that it is correct. When I try to compute the SNF for a $24 \times 24$ matrix, the real time and CPU time are about 0.1~0.2 seconds. I don't think it will take more than 3 hours for a $100 \times 100$ matrix. I have also tried it on several operating systems and the results are similar.

Anyway, what is the approximate time complexity of the computation time of SNF? Is there a limit for the matrix size in Maple to do SNF?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know what algorithm Maple is using, but a 100x100 SNF computation, if the matrix is complicated or if the algorithm isn't very smart, can be a disaster.  A sparse 120x120 matrix in a primitive SNF algorithm can lead to disaster.  You can very easily go past a 64-bit integer size, or start swapping if you are using arbitrary-precision integers. Hafner-McCurley and Havas-Holt-Rees have fairly smart SNF algorithms that can easily handle 400x400 matrices on contemporary computers.

Comment: Just for comparison, you may like to test matsnf() function in the freeware PARI/GP: http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/

Comment: When you say you checked your code, do you mean that you coded a complete SNF algorithm yourself? That would not be a good idea at all!

Comment: For a 120 x 120 matrix of random integers (as produced by RandomMatrix), Maple's SmithForm took 1.338 seconds.

Comment: On the other hand, for polynomials SmithForm takes much longer.  What kind of matrix are you looking at?

Comment: I am looking at matrices with polynomial entries. Sorry for the confusion. I am using the SNF functions provided by linear-algebra package.

Comment: You might try asking Roman Pearce or Michael Monagan about this.  They are very much involved with getting Maple to do efficient linear algebra involving polynomials.

Comment: For any large (and important) computation, you should consider checking multiple CAS's against each other.  Eg Mathematica and Sage in addition to Maple.

Answer (score 6):

(Dense) Smith Normal Form is theoretically computable in $O(\|A\| \log \|A\| N^4\log N)$ time (Arne Storjohann, 1996). Storjohann was at Waterloo at the time, so I would not be surprised if that is the algorithm Maple uses. Sparse SNF is much faster.

Comment: Useful relevant context: [Arne Storjohann: Algorithms for Matrix Canonical Forms. Dissertation 13922. ETH Zurich.](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~astorjoh/diss2up.pdf)